# 2019 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2019 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://opensource.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 5):

**Be bold**: nominate yourself, please!

As a current moderator of the site, I'd encourage you to consider nominating yourself! You might think, "Oh, I don't know if I can or should take on that level of responsibility." I'm here to tell you that you almost certainly can.

I wanted to offer my perspective of transitioning from a 10K-rep user to a moderator. The main thing I can offer is that when I made the switch, **virtually nothing changed**. If you already have close-vote and editing powers, that's basically 95% of what you do as a moderator anyway, especially on a site of this relatively small size. If you already regularly do those things as a user, definitely consider nominating yourself! You'd probably make a great moderator: I can think of many, many regular users who would fill the role excellently.

Yes, the occasional holy-war argument breaks out and turns nasty (about two times per year, I'd estimate), but as long as you have a sufficiently level-headed temperament to say, "Yes, Group X thinks this, Group Y thinks that; let's all move on and answer the question being asked," you'll do just fine.

You might also think, "I wouldn't be so presumptuous to assume that I'm the best pick for moderator," to which I'll say: that's not what nominating yourself means at all. Nominating yourself is a kind of public service. The site needs the best moderators it can get, so if you think it's at all possible that you're up to the job, please nominate yourself and allow the community to decide if you're the best pick.